# Why the size of a html file from Chrome Developer->Network is different with its actually size?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

From Chrome browser developer tools->Network tab, I see the size of one of my html file is 183KB, but after saving this html file to local computer, from its property I can see it's more than 600KB, so why the different here?

Comment: When you saved it, did you choose "HTML Only" or "Complete"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you are inspecting probably [uses compression](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip) (gzip or deflate). It's a common practice to improve website loading time. For example, this StackOverflow page size is 42 KB and it's compressed to 11 KB.